# Perspective correction with OpenCV - Image is cropped to reference marker

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, perspective, aruco

I'm trying a simple perspective correction script with Aruo markers, The script is correctly detecting the Aruco markers and fixes the perspective, But when it outputs the result, The image is cropped to a selected marker, But I need to apply this perspective transformation to the whole image not into a single marker.

The image I attached (untitled7.png) is the input image
Results.png shows what the attached script output now

[image: untitled7.png]
[image: Result.png]

At the end of the day, I need to correct the perspective of the input image so it looks like it is taken from directly above the marker grid

This is my working code now with opencv-contrib-python

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def detect_aruco_and_correct_perspective(image_path):
    # Load the image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Define the ArUco dictionary with the specified parameters (4x4, 250)
    aruco_dictionary = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(
        cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_250)

    # Create ArUco parameters for detection
    aruco_parameters = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters()

    # Detect ArUco markers in the image
    corners, ids, rejected = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(
        image, aruco_dictionary, parameters=aruco_parameters)

    # Check if any markers were detected
    if corners:
        # Assume the first detected marker is our point of interest
        corners = corners[0].reshape((4, 2))

        # Sort the corners to top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left
        top_left = min(corners, key=lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
        top_right = max(corners, key=lambda x: x[0] - x[1])
        bottom_right = max(corners, key=lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
        bottom_left = min(corners, key=lambda x: x[0] - x[1])
        sorted_corners = np.array(
            [top_left, top_right, bottom_right, bottom_left], dtype="float32")

        # Define the size of the new image
        width, height = 500, 500
        destination_corners = np.array(
            [[0, 0], [width - 1, 0], [width - 1, height - 1], [0, height - 1]], dtype="float32")

        # Get the perspective transform matrix
        matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(
            sorted_corners, destination_corners)

        # Apply the perspective transformation
        transformed_image = cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, (width, height))

        return transformed_image
    else:
        return None

transformed_img = detect_aruco_and_correct_perspective(
    'Impacto24_OpenCV-Testings\\v1\\venv\\SampleData\\untitled7.png')
if transformed_img is not None:
    cv2.imshow('Transformed Image', transformed_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
else:
    print('No ArUco markers detected in the image')
```

Any Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you printed your input coordinates and checked where they are in your input image.

Comment: Yes, I did some testing to check where the start and end coordinates are, The programme seems to detect 4 corners then simply drag them to a corner of a square

Comment: calculating the homography from a single marker, when you have an entire board, will be VERY jittery. -- this takes a bunch of matrices, composed using matrix mul. you need matrices for scaling and translation. you compose them onto the homography, from the correct side, and perhaps involving np.linalg.inv(). or you just call `getPerspectiveTransform()` with different points....